# Is my understanding of this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, japanese-to-english

Is my understanding of the sentence below correct?

> いっつもこんなおれの相手してくれてありがと
> Thank you for always being my companion (?)

相手 is companion/partner, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that こんな means "like this". So more literally I would translate this sentence as "Thank you for always being there for me like this" or "Thank you for always taking care of me like this".

As for the main verb according to jisho there are several possible meanings:
相手にする (相手をする) "to keep company", "to listen to", "to look after"...

I personally often see how the particles like に or を get omitted so I suppose this is also the case in this sentence.

Comment: It's こんな***おれ***  not あれ

Comment: I see. Thank you for detailed explanation!